# Pass param via h:link using bean with the same view scope( has a value of null and thus will not be added to the URL)

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, selectonemenu

I have one bean with view scope and want pass parametr between two different pages and on first page before this link I have `<p:selectOneMenu/>` where I choose test which id should be pass as GET param

```
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{addQuestion.test}" id="tests"
    converter="#{testConverter}" required="true" requiredMessage="Please, choose test">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="--Select a test--" itemValue="" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{addQuestion.testList}" var="testItem"
        itemValue="#{testItem}" itemLabel="#{testItem.testName}" />
    <p:ajax process="@this"
        listener="#{addQuestion.getQuestionsBySubject()}"
        update="addingQuestionsTable, testId" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
<h:link value="Add new question" outcome="addQuestion">
    <f:param id="testId" name="testId" value="#{addQuestion.test.testIdentifer.testId}"/>
</h:link>
```

//in second page

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="testId"
        value="#{addQuestion.test.testIdentifer.testId}"
        converter="#{testConverter}" required="true" requiredMessage="Invalid page access. Please use a link from within the system."/>
</f:metadata>
```

And bean

```
@ManagedBean(name = "addQuestion")
@ViewScoped
public class AddQuestion implements Serializable {
    private Test test;
    //get
    //set
}
```

But when I try to get value on second page I nothing to get in expression `#{addQuestion.test.testIdentifer.testId}"` And also in development mode I get

> has a value of null and thus will not be added to the URL.

My `#{testConverter}` is  managed bean in view scope.

How I can pass testId in one bean with view scope and why I get this error?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `<f:xxx>` tags like `<f:param>` doesn't generate any HTML and thus have nothing to update in the HTML DOM tree on ajax request. The `<h:xxx>` components are the ones which generate HTML and are updatable in the HTML DOM tree on ajax request. You need to update the `<h:link>` component instead of the `<f:param>` tag. So, move that `id` from `<f:param>` to `<h:link>`.

```html
<h:link id="testId" value="Add new question" outcome="addQuestion">
    <f:param name="testId" value="#{addQuestion.test.testIdentifer.testId}"/>
</h:link>
```

Comment: And I also have a question. In first page I should send just testId in `<f:param/>` because I can't set validator to param, but on second page value should be set as object in `<f:viewParam/>` or as just id?